# React Axios Get: Cannot display Empty Array

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am new to React and Axios. I want to GET customer data, yet when their address is empty, an Error appeared

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'street' of undefined."

When customer has address, everything works. Is there any way I can make this work without touching the BackEnd?

```
class Account extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      orders: []
    };

componentDidMount() {        
    axios.get(`https://api.mysite.com/customer`)
      .then(res => {
        const orders = res.data;
        this.setState({ orders });
        console.log(orders);
      })
  }

render() {
        return (
<div className="input left">
    {this.state.orders.map(order => <Input className="name" type="text" readOnly value={order.name} />)}
    {this.state.orders.map(order => <Input className="email" type="text" readOnly value={order.email} />)}
    {this.state.orders.map(order => <Input className="password" type="text" readOnly value="*******" />)}
    {this.state.orders.map(order => <Input className="address" type="textarea" readOnly value={order.address[0].street} />)}
    {this.state.orders.map(order => <Input className="phone" type="text" readOnly value={order.address[0].phone} />)}

</div>

        );
    }
}
```

Sorry if the name is confusing, I just copied it from my /order page

Here is the console.log(order) from the WORKING account

```
0:
address: Array(1)
0:
city: "Jakarta Utara"
country: "Indonesia"
created_at: "2019-05-21 10:54:19"
customer_id: "c8ca7ce0-7bb6-11e9-90f8-e1b44f49dcc3"
id: "c8cc3910-7bb6-11e9-b13b-537042a9805b"
name: "fendi"
phone: "0812308123"
postal_code: "14420"
province: "DKI Jakarta"
street: "test"
updated_at: "2019-05-21 10:54:19"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
created_at: "2019-05-21 10:54:19"
email: "test@gmail.com"
email_verified_at: null
id: "c8ca7ce0-7bb6-11e9-90f8-e1b44f49dcc3"
name: "test"
role_id: "a022e290-7bb6-11e9-9fb6-09e2f5236d0a"
updated_at: "2019-05-21 10:54:19"
```

Here is the console.log(order) from the NOT WORKING account

```
0:
address: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
created_at: "2019-05-21 10:53:11"
email: "test@admin.com"
email_verified_at: "2019-05-21 10:53:11"
id: "a02279a0-7bb6-11e9-8711-515da07aadda"
name: "Alisha Stamm"
role_id: "a0156ca0-7bb6-11e9-8ba3-43dcab891f96"
updated_at: "2019-05-21 10:53:11"
```

As can be seen, the account that throws an error doesnt have any address (like street name) and I called .address.street *which is undefined*

Please help, thank you!

Comment: I just wrote you an answer, let me know if that works for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

```
{this.state.orders.map(order => <Input className="address" type="textarea" readOnly value={order.address.length>=0 ? order.address[0].street : ""} />)}
```

Comment: thanks! I didn't think of doing this!
this works when i use order.address.length > 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
    { this.state.orders.map(({ address = [{}] }) => <Input className="address" type="textarea" readOnly value={address[0].street} />) }

    { this.state.orders.map(({ address = [{}] }) => <Input className="phone" type="text" readOnly value={address[0].phone} />) }
```

You can destruct the order object and assign initial values for your object so that conditions like these will not fail. more info here https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment

Answer (score 0):

Yes use a ternary statement in the render method

{this.state.order.street ? (

{this.state.orders.street}

) : (

no street to show here

)}